# Describing speculative challenges for a new method in a paper

Tags: writing

When presenting a new method in a paper and you don't have any/sufficient empirical evidence of the limitations, what is the best way to introduce speculative challenges and potential mitigations?

I'm looking for the title of the section: is this part of the limitations section? my understanding was the limitations had to have empirical evidence.

What wording would be used for introducing them?

Update: the field is interdisciplinary: a mixture of Business Administration and Computer Science.  The method is for Business Administration but relies on some Computer Science techniques and theory.

Comment: I think this is very dependent on field. Can you be specific?

Comment: @Buffy BA and CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about **potential limitations**?

I guess that you have at least some intuition or some loose arguments as to *why* you suspect that the things you are going to describe are indeed (possible) limitations. If not, you should not list them. If yes, add these to the section. Also you could discuss, what would be needed to overcome the limitations.

Comment: I do have some ideas, mostly drawing for challenges for similar methods or components of my method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your results require some preconditions or prerequisites to permit applicability. Do they depend on a particular governmental structure, kind of business, economic system, regulatory regimen, or anything else? You might just start there.

Do the results work over long term or only short term? Do they require cooperation between various players, etc?

It is impossible for an outsider to know, but you could start there and see where it takes you.

Comment: I have listed the preconditions, my method is an extension of an existing framework.   I do have a list of speculative challenges and mitigations, the question for me is where do they fit in the structure of a normal scientific paper.

Comment: If you have worked these limitations into the text proper, it may be enough to point to them in a short "limitations" section, just for the convenience of the reader looking for them. "In section x it is noted that ...". All a bit speculative here, I guess.